# Неправильная работа функции

Tags: php

Доброго дня. Помогите, функция не работает и вешает сайт. Вроде все правильно, помогите понять в чем проблема?

```
function gettranslate($tr_number)
{
$ru=array("НАЙТИ","НОВОСТИ","ОТЗЫВЫ","КОНВЕРТЕР YTL","ПОГОДА","ВРЕМЯ В АЛАНЬЕ","МЫ НА ВЫСТАВКАХ");
$tr=array("bulmak","haber","yorumlar","DÖNÜŞTÜRÜCÜ YTL","hava","Alanya Zaman","Biz gösterir");
$en=array("Find", "News", "review", "CONVERTER YTL", "weather", "time in Alan", "We on Shows");
$de=array("Finden", "News", "bewerten", "Konverter YTL", "wetter", "zeit in Alan", "Wir Shows");

            $f_lang=& JFactory::getLanguage();

            if ($f_lang->getTag() == "en-GB") {$lang_name='en';}
            else if ($f_lang->getTag() == "ru-RU") {$lang_name='ru';}
            else if ($f_lang->getTag() == "tr-TR") {$lang_name='tr';}
            else if ($f_lang->getTag() == "de-DE") {$lang_name='de';}
            else {$lang_name='en';}

            echo ${$lang_name}[$tr_number];    
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Статья на тему, судя по всему, должна помочь](http://omsk777.ru/dollar.html)

Comment: echo ${lang_name}[$tr_number]; - не работает.

Comment: Да блин, зачем вообще все эти извращения... Будьте проще :)


    function gettranslate($tr_number)
    {
        $languages = array
        (
            'ru-RU' => array('русский', ...),
            'en-GB' => array('english', ...);
        );
        $f_lang=& JFactory::getLanguage();
        if( !isset($languages[$f_lang]) $f_lang = 'en-GB';
        echo $languages[$f_lang][$tr_number];
    }

А можно и ещё упростить, но это уже от внешней архитектуры зависит.

Answer (score 0):

А с чего вы взяли, что она должна работать? Попробуйте объяснить хотя бы вот эти две строки:

```
$lang_show ="$"+$lang_name;
echo $lang_show($tr_number);
```

Comment: $lang_show ="$"+$lang_name; - тут ошибся, вы правы 
надо $lang_show =("$" . $lang_name);

Сейчас поменяю текст вопроса.

Comment: Чёрт, форматирование глючит, повторю. В новом варианте вы присвоили переменной $lang_show значение, допустим, "$ru". Операция $lang_show[$tr_number] вернёт символ из этой переменной с индексом $tr_number, то есть сделает ровно то, что и написано. 

Вы ж на самом деле не думаете, что таким образом создаёте динамическую переменную?

Comment: Use a \$$, luke! :)